# How do I indentify an I-frame in H265 stream?

Tags: video-encoding, hevc, video-codecs, h.265

I am working on a C++ application in which my application is receiving H265 frames from an external application and stores it on disk whenever required, but the storing needs to be start only from I-frame because if it starts from P frame, those frames would be meaningless.
So how do I identify the I-frame from it?

I am new to video encoding and decoding and I am aware of following:

- `00 00 00 01` is start of NAL unit
- SPS starts with 67
- PPS starts with 68

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some of the NAL unit types for H.265:

- IDR = 19 or 20
- SPS = 33
- PPS = 34

So your assumption about SPS, PPS values is incorrect.

NAL Unit structure:

"StartCode" "Byte" "Payload"

To get the NAL unit type you have to do `(Byte >> 1) & 0x3f`.

You need to look for an IDR frame (instant decoder refresh; type 19 or 20).

Comment: Yes. Later I figured out the sps and pps start byte I know is only of h264. After some experiments and research I was able to figure out the exact way for it. It has to be ```(byte >> 1) & 0x3F```

Comment: Excellent - if I have answered your question - please mark my answer accordingly - thanks.